# Сделать файл отражающий все изменениями в проекте без использования git/svn

Tags: git, phpstorm, svn

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать файл со всеми изменениями в проекте за определенный период, а именно что и в какой файл было внесено. Изменения вносились с помощью phpStorm. Git и svn в данном проекте не использовались. Надеюсь вопрос понятен)

Comment: Некоторые IDE могут скидывать версии файлов в папку `_history\` например. Проверьте, у вас подобной нет?

Comment: Скорей начинайте использовать Git или Mercurial, на худой конец SVN. Без контроля версий - разве что вы сохранили предыдущую версию проекта в другую папку или архив, или как Kromster предлагает, в истории среды разработки.

Comment: использую svn. но с этим проектом все не просто (долго объяснять)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если системы контроля версий не использовались, проследить изменения будет невозможно.

Comment: в ide нет такой функции?

Comment: нет нету. ide, сама по себе никак не фиксирует текущее состояние проекта. но можно например подключить git к ide и фиксировать (делать коммит) состояние проекта используя интерфейс ide

Comment: в вебшторме была локальная история изменения файла, т.к. я точно заходил проверить изменения, когда vcs ещё не была подключена. но она вроде относительно краткосрочная

Comment: Правду говорите, локальная история там есть. Посмотрите что там осталось, там принцип теневого копирования, может и осталось что надо. Файл->local history